# React to chat-commands (webhooks)

Tags: php, webhooks, discord

So I have a pretty easy setup for a bot on discord:

```
<?php

function postToDiscord($message)
{
    $data = array(
        "content" => $message,
        "username" => "myBot",
    );
    $curl = curl_init("https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/MY_HOOK");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    return curl_exec($curl);
}

postToDiscord("foo bar");
```

This works as expected, but I don't get the concept of these hooks. I saw [an example](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/de/articles/228383668) here with github, but this reacts on actions made with github. Like, after a commit, i can trigger a webhook and post to a channel.

However, I'd like to react to specific chat-commands like `!song` to retrieve the current song from spotify. On twitch for example, I know you can grab the current text from an IRC, but how does this work for discord?

I think I need an observer, which reacts to a given input (maybe with an ajax-call?). Any ideas or feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your example is meant as a one way communication channel. You would post to that URL (as you're already doing) to just send messages into that channel. You would have to look into [this](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#get-channel-messages) in order to actually read messages. You could probably look into [DiscordPHP](https://github.com/teamreflex/DiscordPHP) to get an understanding on how to utilize it. It should be as easy as just doing a `GET` on `discordapp.com/api/channels/{channel.id}/messages`. Might need to implement a bot though (so it acts as a dummy user)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Discord WebHooks can only Post they can't fetch